# In joomla how can we Increase "Remember Me" cookie time

Tags: joomla

I want to Increase "Remember Me" cookie time for 10 year.
How can i do it without core file Hack.

Answer (score 0):

Hey Ravi,
 You can use this plugin http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/administration/admin-desk/13982

Hope this help you.

Edit: Though Its commercial ($2)